# Drawing a trendline using matplotlib

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib, graph, trendline

I've been trying to graph some price v time data, and I cannot figure a way of drawing a trendline here. The dates are datetime objects. The graph is fine. However, using polyfit as I do below throws up an error.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
from datetime import datetime
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as plb

notes = pd.read_csv("tsla.csv")
notes.dropna(inplace=True)
date_list = notes['x']
price_list = notes['Close']

date_list = date_list.tolist()
price_list = price_list.tolist()

for i in range(len(date_list)):
    date_list[i] = (date_list[i][:-8])
    date_list[i] = date_list[i][:-5] + date_list[i][-3:-1]
    ##print(len(date_list[i]))
    date_list[i] = datetime.strptime(date_list[i], "%m/%d/%y")
    ##print(date_list[i])

##print(date_list)

price_list = list(map(lambda x: int(x), price_list))

plt.plot(date_list, price_list)
plt.ylabel("Prices")
plt.xlabel("Dates")

# calc the trendline (it is simply a linear fitting)
z = np.polyfit(date_list, price_list, 1)
p = np.poly1d(z)
plb.plot(x,p(x),"r--")

##### Showing time series line graph below
plt.show()
```

Error below

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ramapriyansrivatsanpd/Documents/Python for finance - fintech soc.py", line 42, in <module>
    z = np.polyfit(date_list, price_list, 1)
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 5, in polyfit
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/lib/polynomial.py", line 590, in polyfit
    x = NX.asarray(x) + 0.0
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'datetime.datetime' and 'float'
```

Comment: Could you give an example of `notes['x']`?

Answer (score 0):

I know it's 10 months but maybe you or some other people

You could cast the Y-Axis to `int()` and the X-Axis to `datetime`-Object after that `x = mdates.date2num(x)`.

After this it worked for me.